# Converting C# Console Application to ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods

I have a basic console application in C# that copies files from one location to another. I am attempting to transfer this over to an ASP.NET MVC App but am still learning the basic architecture of where to store my methods. I am under the impression most methods get store as ActionResults in the controller, but this is where I start to get confused.

**My question: where do I put my c# methods/variables (controller or model?) and what is the best way to call on the method. I am currently calling on it through the view.**

Notes:

1. I show an error within my controller for the copyFiles method stating 'not all code paths return a value'. This does not display in my Console version. I wonder if I need to move this under my DisplayCustomer ActionResult.
2. My DisplayCustomer View generates an error within the if statement under @copyFiles saying it does not exist in current content, which confuses me because I have it defined in the model I am using.

I apologize if this is overly complicated. Thank you very much.

```
**Model:**
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcCustomer.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string SourceSystem { get; set; }
        public string Environment { get; set; }
        public void copyFiles(int numberOfFiles)
        {
            List<string> files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\Test", "*").ToList();
            IEnumerable<string> filesToCopy = files.Where(file => file.Contains("Test_File")).Take(10);

            foreach (string file in filesToCopy)
            {
                // here we set the destination string with the file name
                string destfile = @"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\RenameFolder\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
                // now we copy the file to that destination
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, destfile, true);
            };
        }

    }
}

**View:**
@model MvcCustomer.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayCustomer";
}

<h2>Tests to be executed:</h2>
<body>
    <div>
        The Source System is @Model.SourceSystem <br />
        The Environment is @Model.Environment <br />
    </div>
    @{var SourceSystem=Model.SourceSystem; }

        @if (SourceSystem == "TestSourceSystem")
        {
            @copyFiles(10); //This is where my error is
        }    
</body>

**Controller:**
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcCustomer.Models;
using MvcCustomer.Controllers;

namespace MvcCustomer.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult DisplayCustomer()
        {
            Customer obj = new Customer();
            obj.SourceSystem = Request.Form["SourceSystem"];
            obj.Environment = Request.Form["Environment"];
            return View(obj);
        }

        public ActionResult copyFiles(int numberOfFiles)
        {
            List<string> files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\ProductionBEARS", "*").ToList();
            IEnumerable<string> filesToCopy = files.Where(file => file.Contains("Test_File")).Take(10);

            foreach (string file in filesToCopy)
            {
                // here we set the destination string with the file name
                string destfile = @"C:\Users\acars\Desktop\RenameFolder\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
                // now we copy the file to that destination
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, destfile, true);
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: copyFiles() is declared to return an ActionResult, yet you return nothing.

Comment: Should I remove the ActionResult, or insert a return View(); at the end? This is the part that confuses me because I just want to run the method, which doesn't necessarily need to return a view, so I am probably structuring it incorrectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of transferring the `Console Application` to a `Web Project`, I think it is better to create an `MVC Application` from scratch and move your methods in the `Console Application` to the new `MVC Application`. I suggest to have a look at one of the basic and useful tutorial having demo project on [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was attempting to do, but it may not have been clear in the code since I'm new to this. I'm just a little unsure of where to house my methods for copying files, and the best way to call on them. I know it's high level! I'll take a look at the reading. Thanks again!

Comment: Beside this, I would also recommend you to have a look at the wonderful videos on [AP:NET MVC Videos](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos) and [Pluralsight ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-aspnet-mvc-5-fundamentals). Especially Pluralsight's video tutorials are really very good for MVC.